# How can I input the edge attribute as an explanatory variable in my exponential random graph model?

Tags: r, network-analysis

I am working on using exponential random graph model to do network analysis. I use the **`igraph`** and **`ergm`** packages in R.

The network I am working on is created by the following function:

```
 `bd11 <- network::as.network(as.matrix(a1), 
                            directed=FALSE)
 network::set.vertex.attribute(bd11, "Industry", 
                          C1$Industry)
 network::set.vertex.attribute(bd11, "Tobin'sq", 
                          C1$Tobin.s.q)
 network::set.vertex.attribute(bd11, "Previousdegree", 
                          D1$Degree)
 network::set.edge.attribute(bd11, "Previous", 
                          alignment1$Ali)`
```

Currently, the model performs best is as followed:
    `ergm(bd11 ~ edges+ 
    +gwesp(0.3,fixed=T)+match("Tobin'sq")+match("Industry"))`

I include the homophily effects of node attributes "Tobin's q" and "Industry" in the model specifying.

However, I did not find any command in the ergm function allow me to input edge attribute in the model.

In my network data, I have an edge attribute variable that indicates whether the edge exists in another network ("previous" as the above function indicated). It is a dummy vairable indicates yes or no. I assume that the connection in the other network has influence on the current network forming, so I want to include the edge attribute in the ergm model. Could someone provides me some suggestion about how to do that? I did not find any command in "ergm" function that allow me to take care of edge attribute.  Or maybe there is a clever way to transfer the edge attribute to node attribute ? I appreciate a lot!

I have to apology that I could not share my data due to confidential issue. Thanks a lot for kind considering.

Comment: Hi Jingy ; this question is likely to get closed (as three users have voted to close already). Can you try to edit it with a small graph (random?), and show how you use functions from the ergm package, as this may more clearly indicate what you need.

Comment: Maybe you can provide some dummy data and code for us to make it more understandable..